# Create an Age Array using for

Tags: arrays, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm creating an age selector, I have set all the carousel, and the screen, but I'm having a problem setting the array to be from 20 years until 80, what I have done to test was this

```
const dataAge = [
  {age: '21'},
  {age: '22'},
  {age: '23'},
  {age: '24'},
  {age: '25'},
  {age: '26'},
  {age: '27'},
  {age: '28'},
  {age: '29'},
  {age: '30'},
  {age: '31'},
  {age: '32'},
  {age: '33'},
  {age: '34'},
  {age: '35'},
  {age: '36'},
];
```

but I wasn't able to use a FOR to solve this problem

this is the code where the array will be inserted

```
<View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: '#FFF',
            flex: 0.18,
            borderRadius: 10,
            margin: 10,
          }}>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
            }}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 15, margin: 10, alignItems: 'flex-start'}}>
              Age
            </Text>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 10,
                alignItems: 'flex-end',
                margin: 10,
              }}>
              years old
            </Text>
          </View>
          {/* Age picker */}
          <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Carousel
              data={dataAge}
              renderItem={renderItemAge}
              sliderWidth={300}
              itemWidth={30}
              horizontal={true}
              firstItem={5}
              enableMomentum={true}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.TriangleShapeView}></View>
        </View>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What's the React component that needs this array? What shape of data does it require?

Comment: Just added the rest of the code

Comment: Could you also share the `import` statement of `Carousel`? That will help us determine what shape `data` needs to be.

Comment: have you tried the answer posted below?

Comment: In your question, you say that the array starts from 20, but in your code, it starts from 21. Should 20 years also be included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the array and push the objects to it:

```
let dataAge = [];

for (let i = 20; i <= 80; i++) {
    dataAge.push({ age: i.toString() });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let age = 20;
let dataAge = Array.from({ length: 61 }, () => {
  let obj = { age: age.toString() };
  age++;
  return obj;
});

console.log(dataAge);
```